# Initial position on a Map Fragment with .setRetainInstance

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

So I have the following things that are working properly:

I have a map fragment and I have markers on my map. Using .setRetainInstance on my map fragment does exactly what I want, on rotate it keeps the user zoomed  position and keeps the markers on their place. The only thing that I want to do now is to make the initial screen of the app to move the camera to a exact location and zoom level. I am doing that with the initialLocation method which if added in the onMapReady does what its supposed to. The problem is that once I add this method inside onMapReady the setRetainInstance is not working anymore, on each rotation the map resets to the initialLocation position. As u will probably realize from my code I am just learning this and I have read a lot of tutorials, but I cannot manage to make it right. Here is part of the code so you can have an idea of what I am talking about. I guess I have to add some sort of conditions in order for this to work. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
private static final double
        TOULOUSE_LAT = 43.604346,
        TOULOUSE_LNG = 1.443760;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            mapTypeSelected = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
            mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);

        } else {
            mapTypeSelected = savedInstanceState.getInt("the_map_type", GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }

  @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        initialLocation(TOULOUSE_LAT,TOULOUSE_LNG, 12);
        mMap.setMapType(mapTypeSelected);


        addMarkers2Map();// method for adding markers and a lot of other stuff...

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("the_map_type", mapTypeSelected);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.get("the_map_type");

    }

    private void initialLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom){
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng );
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a member variable similar to this:

```
Boolean mSetCameraPosition;
```

Then in `onCreate()` set the value of mSetCameraPosition before calling `getMapAsync()`:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    mapTypeSelected = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
    mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    mSetCameraPosition = true;
}
else {
    mapTypeSelected = savedInstanceState.getInt("the_map_type", GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mSetCameraPosition = false;
}
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

In `onMapReady()` use `mSetCameraPosition`:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (mSetCameraPosition) {
        initialLocation(TOULOUSE_LAT,TOULOUSE_LNG, 12);
    }

    mMap.setMapType(mapTypeSelected);

    addMarkers2Map(); // method for adding markers and a lot of other stuff...
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, except the fact that in savedInstanceState == null the mSetCameraPosition has to be equal with true and with false in the else statement. Thanks a lot!